# How to serialize record sum data type in Aeson without tag?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have data type with multiple constructors, for example

```
data AB = A 
  { 
    ab :: Text
  , a :: Text
  } 
  | B 
  {
    ab :: Text
  , b :: Text
  } deriving (Generic)
```

Right now when I use Aeson to serialize `A` it generated to following JSON:

```
{
  "tag": "A",
  "ab": "some text",
  "a": "some text"
}
```

I know that it's possible to use [`SumEncoding`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html#t:SumEncoding) to manipulate how constructor will be handled, but could not find what I want.

Is it possible somehow to omit `tag` field in serialized JSON? I need only one way serialization (no reason to keep it to deserialize it), but data type is pretty big to write how to serialize it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky way is to simply delete the `tag` from the resulting object:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.HashMap.Strict
import Data.String
import Data.Text
import GHC.Generics

data AB
  = A { ab :: Text
      , a  :: Text
      }
  | B { ab :: Text
      , b  :: Text
      }
  deriving Generic

instance ToJSON AB where
  toJSON ab = case genericToJSON defaultOptions ab of
    Object o -> Object (delete (fromString "tag") o)
    _ -> error "impossible"
```

It'll probably come back to bite you when the generic instance inevitably changes, though, so if you do this, be conscious of the technical debt you are choosing to take on.

Comment: I guess it's better to take it and wait or contribute to Aeson. That hack was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[`Options`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Options) has a [`sumEncoding`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:sumEncoding) field, and [`defaultOptions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:defaultOptions) sets this to [`defaultTaggedObject`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:defaultTaggedObject).

Setting it to `UntaggedValue` (from [`SumEncoding`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:SumEncoding), available in aeson-1.0.0.0 and later) should do what you're looking for.

Comment: To give an example, I think this is the minimal code needed for both serialization and deserialization to work without tag:
data Foo = FooA { x :: Int } | FooB { y :: Int } deriving (Generic, Show);
instance ToJSON Foo where
    toEncoding = genericToEncoding (defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue });
instance FromJSON Foo where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON (defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue });

Answer (score 3):

Just define the `ToJSON` instance yourself:

```
instance ToJSON AB where
    toJSON (A ab a) = object [ "ab" .= ab, "a" .= a ]
    toJSON (B ab a) = object [ "ab" .= ab, "a" .= a ]

ab1 = A "foo" "bar"
ab2 = A "abc" "def"

*Main> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LBS
*Main LBS> LBS.putStrLn $ encode ab2
{"ab":"abc","a":"def"}
*Main LBS> LBS.putStrLn $ encode ab1
{"ab":"foo","a":"bar"}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing code to serialize it manually due to relatively big number of properties (some of them `Maybe`, some nested) and number of constructors. But if there is no other option, I will go with it

Comment: @klappvisor It shouldn't matter whether your fields are nested or `Maybe`s, so long as each field's type is a `ToJSON` instance.

Comment: @DanielWagner I use `defaultOptions { omitNothingFields = True }` so I guess I have to if I want to omit them